# Автозагрузка классов PHP 7.4 + LAMP

Tags: php, linux, lamp

Писал все проекты на Windows + PhpStorm + OpenServer.

Перешел на linux Mint + PhpStorm + LAMP

Как обычно все начинается с index.php и сразу попал на проблему что не грузится класс.

```
use Core\Launcher;

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR."core");
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();

$Launcher = new Launcher();
$Launcher->Setup();
```

Подскажите в чем проблема?!

Ошибка на экране:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Core\Launcher' not found in /home/verstala/Сервер/verstala.com/index.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/verstala/Сервер/verstala.com/index.php on line 14
```

Comment: Какой именно класс не грузится?

Comment: Не грузится Launcher

Answer (score 0):

Перед `use Core\Launcher;` сделайте подключение самого файла, где находится класс `require 'class.php';`